# LINQPad: Reference single-file app in query

Tags: linqpad, .net-core-publishsinglefile

I have an app with multiple C# project. The app gets published as a single-file to make deployment a lot easier. Now I want to reference this single .exe /.dll in a LINQPad query to use types inside it.

I tried to add the reference as usual but this does not work.

Is this possible?

I'm using LINQPad 7.7.15 (x64)

Comment: I suspect not. AFAIK the exe is no longer pure IL and can't be loaded by System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile. If you don't have access to the individual dlls,then you would need to extract the assemblies from your exe (e.g. using https://github.com/Droppers/SingleFileExtractor/ ) and then reference the extracted dlls.